# Traversing a json object returns only the last of each key, while keeping the needed DOM structure

Tags: jquery, json

below I have written a couple of functions to traverse a JSON object and build a DOM tree of divs to kinda mirror the JSON structure in a GUI form, I know that it traverses the entire object, but the issue is that it is only displaying the last item of one of the nodes.

This is the DOM tree that it displays:

```
        <div>
            Users
            <div>
                test
                <div>
                    lastName
                    <div>
                         Test
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the code:

```
        function convert(obj){

              for (var key in obj){
                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                          var div = document.createElement('div');
                          div = $(div);
                          div.text(key)

                          var child = convertElement(obj[key]);
                          div.append(child);
                    }
              }
              return div;
        }

        function convertElement(element){
              switch (typeof(element)){
                    case 'object':
                          return convert(element);
                          break;
                    case 'array':
                          return convert(element);
                          break;
                    case 'string':
                          return divify(element);
                          break;
                    case 'number':
                          return divify(element);
                          break;
                    case 'boolean':
                          return divify(element);
              }
        }     

        function divify(element){
              var div = document.createElement('div');
              div = $(div)
              div.text(element);
              return div;
        }
```

Comment: The most nested item will be returned because that will be the `div` variable after the loop ends. Please describe what functionality you want. Would you want to return all items in the DOM tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in your code here:

```
function convert(obj) {

    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              var div = document.createElement('div');
              div = $(div);
              div.text(key)

              var child = convertElement(obj[key]);
              div.append(child);
        }
    }
    return div;
}
```

Notice that a new `div` is created for each key in the `obj`. As such the last `div` will be the last created element after the loop is done. In this case above it would be the one with the text `"Test"`. What you need to do if you want all the elements is store them in an array and `.push()` each created `<div>` into that array. This way you will return your entire DOM tree (Where the first element is the most outer `div` and the last one the most inner) other than just the last item:

```
var divs = [];
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div = $(div);
        div.text(key)

        var child = convertElement(obj[key]);
        div.append(child);
        divs.push(div);
     }
}
return divs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to convert JSON to DOM ( [Click here to View Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ypy24sfv/15/) )

```
var my_json = {
    "name" : "Jakob",
    "Job Title" : "Software Engineer",
    "Platforms" : ["OSX", "Windows", "Linux"]
};

function obj_to_dom(obj) {
    var parent = $("<div></div>");
    $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
        var child = $("<div></div>");
        child.text(key);
        child.append(to_dom(val));
        parent.append(child);
    });
    return parent;
}

function arr_to_dom(arr) {
    var parent = $("<div></div>");
    $.each(arr, function(i, val) {
        parent.append(to_dom(val));
    });
    return parent;
}

function literal_to_dom(literal) {
    var parent = $("<div></div>");
    parent.text(literal);
    return parent;
}

function to_dom(obj) {
    if( $.isArray(obj) )
        return arr_to_dom(obj);
    if( $.isPlainObject(obj) )
        return obj_to_dom(obj);
    return literal_to_dom(obj);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var my_dom = to_dom(my_json);
    $("body").append(my_dom);
});
```

We can use the JQuery's JSON and Array iterating functions, "$.each". This will make it compatible across all browsers. Also we divide the job across small functions to keep it simple and more readable.